.htaccess redirect for URL with parameters does not work
In the following .htaccess, redirecting oldsite.com to newsite.com works fine. But I also want to redirect URLs with parameters from the old site and this does not work:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=4$
RewriteRule http://newsite.com/about/ [QSD,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

The URL "oldsite.com/?page_id=4" redirects to "newsite.com/?page_id=4" and not to "newsite.com/about/". The .htaccess file on newsite.com is the usual WordPress with nothing added. What am I doing wrong?

You ask: "what am I doing wrong?"
Answer: you implemented a syntax error and did not notice that fact.
The rule RewriteRule http://newsite.com/about/ [QSD,R=301,L] is not valid syntax. You forgot the matching pattern that is mandatory. Interesting enough you did specify that pattern in the following rule.
You would notice that issue when looking at your http server's error log file. That is where such issues are logged to. Note: you cannot operate an http server without monitoring that file!

Take a look at that slightly modified example instead:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=4$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://newsite.com/about/ [QSD,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

I took the liberty to suggest a few other changes as well.
